# IBM HTTP Server Memory Limit Recommended

Tags: websphere, httpserver, ibmhttpserver

I have some instances of IHS working with more than 75% of memory usage. Is there any official recommendation for this max memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

Is it high or growing unbounded?  Are you measuring the RSS of each process or some system-wide metric?

If it's just high, you can make sure you aren't creating far more threads/processes then needed by looking at mod_mpmstats output over time then reducing things like MinSpareThreads.  Additionally, MaxMemFree may help.

If you have unbounded growth, you can use MaxSpareThreads and MaxRequestsPerChild to recycle processes regularly.